# Holding my breath

Tags: meditation-breath

I don't breath appropriately.
Most of the time i hold my breath its like I'm tensed.
When i was a child i started doing this when i was near people but today (40 years old) i hold my breath all the time even when i walk.
When i am sleeping i breath appropriately.
I have developed a lot of problems like Photophobia and Phonophobia .
Is there any exercise that can make me breath appropriately?

Comment: Looks like a medical condition to me. You should consult a doctor.

Comment: I was. He said that i need to exercise ‏breathing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to breathe mindfully; be aware of in breaths and out breaths and also be aware of the length of the breath more often. Make it so that there is a proper rhythm to it, and a habit.

Important bit is to combine it with mindfulness practice in a gentle fashion - stressing gentle.

On the other hand, how wonderful that you will be doing it mindfully with such purpose!

There is also a beautiful yoga in Dzogchen tradition called Yantra Yoga that is a yoga of breath; it is worth taking up classes for great benefit.